# Backup WhatsApp from NANDROID

Tags: root-access

Hi guys: refering to this:
[Restore Whatsapp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169607/restore-whatsapp/214064#214064)

Get the same issue.

I just reset all my phone after an OTA bricked.

I made an nandroid backup, but, i dunno how to acces - on my phone - the "data/data/com.whatsapp" file to read owner and group.
I think for the nandroid its going to be ok.

Cheers

Comment: Hint: Linux Shell: Use the `Tab key` to autocomplete long names of directories and files while in the command line (you can also use `*` as wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

**install WhatsApp, then boot in TWRP and look from adb shell**

- show the folder attributes with the `ls` command

  ```
  ls -dln /data/data/com.whatsapp
  ```

example output:

```
mint@debian ~ $ adb shell
/ # ls -dln /data/data/com.whatsapp
drwx------   13 10104    10104         4096 Jan 15 04:15 /data/data/com.whatsapp
```

**next, restore the backup (or part of it)**

- download [open-gapps-pico.zip](https://opengapps.org) for your platform (ARM) to PC
- extract the tar binary (tar-arm for ARM) and push it to phone (in TWRP)

  ```
  adb push C:\adb\tar-arm /tmp/
  ```
- open adb shell and make the binary executable (TWRP)

  ```
  chmod 0750 /tmp/tar-arm
  ```

example output:

```
mint@debian ~/Downloads $ adb push tar-arm /tmp/
387 KB/s (427448 bytes in 1.075s)
mint@debian ~/Downloads $ adb shell
/ # chmod 0750 /tmp/tar-arm
```

- in TWRP look for the location where your (internal/external) sdcard is mounted

  ```
  df
  ```

example output:

```
/ # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  1010636        44   1010592   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1010636        28   1010608   0% /tmp
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19   253920      2380    246300   1% /cache
/dev/block/mmcblk0p20 11608792   9847780   1728244  85% /data
/dev/block/mmcblk0p20 11608792   9847780   1728244  85% /sdcard
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1  31150720  22588512   8562208  73% /external_sd
```

- find the backup folder with the `ls` and `cd` commands

example output for `cd` change directory:

```
/ # cd /external_sd
/external_sd # cd TWRP
/external_sd/TWRP # cd BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG
```

example output for `ls` list files and folders:

```
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG # ls
2019-03-20--03-44-24_CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V16_20180517
2019-04-16--08-03-32_CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V16_20180517
2019-04-21--07-15-28_CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V22_20181228
2019-06-18--20-30-44_CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V16_20180517
2019-06-23--05-37-30_CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V16_20180517
2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180
```

enter the latest backup folder (you can also use `*` as wildcard)

```
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG # cd 2019-06-26*
```

list `ls` the backup file names inside. the interesting is the data.ext4.win* backup

```
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # ls
boot.emmc.win          data.ext4.win002       recovery.emmc.win.md5
boot.emmc.win.md5      data.ext4.win002.md5   recovery.log
data.ext4.win000       data.ext4.win003       system.ext4.win
data.ext4.win000.md5   data.ext4.win003.md5   system.ext4.win.md5
data.ext4.win001       data.info              system.info
data.ext4.win001.md5   recovery.emmc.win
```

- Before unpacking, find the required file name(s) which contains your whatsapp files. use the `tar-arm` binary with parameters `-t` (test) and look into each file `-f data.ext4.win*`, while the error output is filtered out with `2> /dev/null` and the the file list is filtered for folder name `/data/data/com.whatsapp` with the `grep` command

  ```
  /tmp/tar-arm -tf data.ext4.win000 2> /dev/null | grep /data/data/com.whatsapp
  ```

example output: (no result for `data.ext4.win000` `data.ext4.win001` `data.ext4.win002`)

```
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # /tmp/tar-arm -tf data.ext4.win000 2> /dev/null | grep /data/data/com.whatsapp
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # /tmp/tar-arm -tf data.ext4.win001 2> /dev/null | grep /data/data/com.whatsapp
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # /tmp/tar-arm -tf data.ext4.win002 2> /dev/null | grep /data/data/com.whatsapp
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # /tmp/tar-arm -tf data.ext4.win003 2> /dev/null | grep /data/data/com.whatsapp
/data/data/com.whatsapp/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/cache/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/code_cache/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/lib
/data/data/com.whatsapp/app_minidumps/
^C
```

- now you can extract the folder `/data/data/com.whatsapp` (as last argument) from the file(s) `-f data.ext4.win003` with the `tar-arm` binary with `-x` and additional parameters `--selinux` `--xattrs` `-p` for file attributes, while `-P` will keep the leading `/` which will restore everything to `/data` and `-v` make the whole thing more visible for you. handle each data.ext4.win* file for its own:

  ```
  /tmp/tar-arm --selinux --xattrs -vxpPf data.ext4.win003 /data/data/com.whatsapp
  ```

example output:

```
/external_sd/TWRP/BACKUPS/CUBOT_KING_KONG/2019-06-26--08-30-17_du_s3ve3g-userdebug_712_NZH54D_engroot20180 # /tmp/tar-arm --selinux --xattrs -vxpPf data.ext4.win003 /data/data/com.whatsapp
/data/data/com.whatsapp/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/cache/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/code_cache/
/data/data/com.whatsapp/lib
/data/data/com.whatsapp/app_minidumps/
^C
```

**finally, change the owner and group**

```
/ # chown -Rh 10104.10104 /data/data/com.whatsapp
```

Comment: Hum... So, as a Windows user: - reinstall Whatsapp - reboot on TWRP - on computer, go in my ADB Folder, open a CMD, and go for a -> adb shell - check with -> ls -dln /data/data/com.whatsapp - take a note on group number and owner number

Next: how to restore my data/data/com.whatsapp ?

Then: - go back on my ADB shell, and change group and owner - reboot phone

Am i right ?

Comment: so your question is, how to extract a single app from nandroid backup - i will update my answer in a few hours

Comment: hi @alecxs and thx for your help. That's huge. Unfortunately, after the chown -Rh 10238.10238 /data/data/com.whatsapp, i reboot to android, and when i try to launch WhatsApp, i have a really quick message (have to take a video screen and look at it slowly): WhatsApp immediately stopped. Any idea ?

Comment: maybe the secontext must also changed, or folder permissions. try `chmod 0775 /data/data/com.whatsapp` or `chcon -Rh u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 /data/data/com.whatsapp`

Comment: My GOD: LOVE YOU SO HARD BRO !!! Works perfectly with a 0775 <3<3

Comment: Let just get my MMS back, and i'm full ok after that. And for sure, i'm going to check about all my cloud backups seriously now xD

Comment: try just one single file `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/smsmms.db`

Comment: Yeah. Ive extract this one and made a backup. But no attachments