# transfer android data from nandroid or twrp backup to new phone

Tags: twrp, restore, nandroid

My old phone has broken screen and I managed to get Userdata as TWRP and Nandroid Backup.

I Need to extract from either backup (below are the priorities from up to down)

- Contacts
- Call logs
- Messages
- Whatsapp data
- Viber data
- Skype data
- Telegram data
- Game data for one or two games

Old phone with broken is Nexus 5(hammerhead) with marshmallow 
New phone is Nexus 5x (bullhead) with LineageOS ROM (Oreo)

Unfortunately I can't find programs or instructions how to extract and transfer to a new phone. Could you provide an instruction how to do it manually?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214065 https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3259492

Comment: as I understand whatsapp instructions will work for others too?

Comment: yes, basically the chown is important. there is a text file /data/system/packages.list containing all uids

Comment: maybe easier way.. from twrp adb shell modify build.prop to enable usb-debugging. you need [persist.service.adb.enable=1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/120394) and [ro.adb.secure=0](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116) then you can run [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) and install [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763)

Comment: where do I set ro.adb.secure=0?

Comment: i am not sure if it works in build.prop or only default.prop but i have linked all necessary information (including other method placing RSA key into /data/misc/adb)