# Export accounts from Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: backup, microsoft-authenticator

I have Google Authenticator and Microsoft Authenticator. I want to move both off my main phone and onto two backup phones, mainly in case my main phone is ever lost or stolen. Walking around with all my security and bank accounts on my main phone makes me feel vulnerable to a 5-dollar wrench attack.

Google Authenticator seems fairly painless. You export the sites you want to export.

I can't see how you can do it with Microsoft Authenticator. I tried installing it on another phone and restoring it, but then the first phone ended up being blocked for about 15 minutes.

How can I do this with Microsoft Authenticator?

Comment: Related/possible dupe for a rooted device: [Is it possible to restore the data of Microsoft Authenticator from a TWRP backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236356/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can't be done, at least not through regular means. MS Authenticator doesn't let you see the secret or export it. But, it gives you the chance to recover them on a new device (if backup was already set up on the old one). Moreover, one wrong step while recovering and the whole backup could be overwritten.

Comment: That seems to be my impression as well. I'm thinking of migrating everything to Google authenticator