# msgstore.db nightmare on my WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore, app-data, sqlite

I have a 780 MB `msgstore.db` `WhatsApp` file that I recovered when my  phone data was corrupted ( from the available image - data recovery software).
now the issue is that I have the UN encrypted `msgstore.db` file available and the encrypted files that is `dbcrypt` or  whatever they go by - those were not recoverable
when I open this 780 MB file with a `SQL lite reader` I can browse the `database` so it is not corrupt.
I have yet another 580 MB `msgstore.db` 
which is corrupt and the desktop software cannot read. this is the original file that I recovered from the corrupted `image` and I had hoped to restore this very file after i wiped  my data and Re installed  Stock `ROM` 

after wiping and new ROM installation
`WhatsApp` went to the `cloud` (
`Google Drive`)
and created A 380 MB  `msgstore.db`
this file has a lot of my chats missing

so here are my questions please help me I am stranded without WhatsApp for the last two weeks 
-- even though msgstore.db can be read on my desktop , if I remove 380 MB `msgstore.db` & put  the 780mb msgstore.db
in  `/data/data/com WhatsApp/data bases` and clear `cache` , `WhatsApp` gives a message that it has trouble reading my chats please wait while it tries to restore and then it will look for the DB crypt files.
- read about  `WhatsApp xtracto`r
if I use this `Python` based `bat script` & 
extract  messages as HTML from the 580 MB and 780 MB files,  **how can I import them back to `WhatsApp` so that my chat is restored** .
-also read a  method of merging > 2  `msgstore.db` files. but seeing the fact that a non corrupt 780mb file got rejected , is this a  viable option

Comment: you forgot to set file permissions especially uid/gid https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169607

Comment: 755 & `root` owns them. Thanks so.much didn't realize that.I will `Chown ` them to `WhatsApp` but the symptoms in that post are  different from what i see here. But will give it a.shot & inform.`755` ahould still be good for reads .

Comment: with root permissions it can not work. look for "userid" in `/data/system/packages.xml` - most important file on android

Comment: ok Thank you again.

Comment: sounds.like `WhatsApp` ` uid .& gid` aee already copied when u copied over the foles  even though they were owned by `root ` . i.didnt do any chow  or octal change. I still keep getting the same error message it looks like your chat cannot be read. something else going on

Comment: First delete /data/data/com.whatsapp then reboot and check secontext too with ls -Z

Comment: there is nothing special from `selinux` that could call attention . Here goes the o/p `ls -Z`

Comment: ` # ls -Z /data/data/com.whatsapp
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 app_light_prefs
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 app_minidumps
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 app_textures
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 app_webview
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 cache
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 code_cache
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 databases
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 files
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 lib
<etc>
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 shared_prefs
dreameltemtr:/ #`

Comment: what I did find out was after I added the 780mb `msgstore.db` it did try and read it ..for a moment I could see the messages after which I got the `SQLite` error message. Malformed database. But this is NOT a malformed db. I can open  it in  SQLite Browser.Another observation : after sometime , the 780mb file just got deleted. The pre-existing file  being renamed there wasnt `msgstore.db` around & it tried to do a chat restore again . I then restored the earlier 'valid' `msgstore.db`  & take it from there

Comment: have not solved it anywhere close. still in the same quandry I am missing about six months of WhatsApp message data that I can see on a desktop but I cant put it back on WhatsApp.