# WhatsApp "something when wrong with your chat history" and msgstore.db got automatically deleted

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, application-error

I have this problem since updated my Whatsapp to latest version where at random time it will crash and display a notification saying:
[image: Whatsapp error]

It happens so many times throughout the day.
I have a rooted phone. And when that happens I can see that my `msgstore.db` from `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` is completely gone others like `wa.db`,etc are left untouched.

I have backed up my `msgstore.db` somewhere in my phone and I can just copy that to the `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` no problem, but sure enough sometime in the day same error pop up and my `msgstore.db` got wiped.

The easiest way to trigger this error by simply back up my chat in the settings and enable google drive upload, when the local backup complete and the backup showing "preparing google drive backup..." The Whatsapp just simply crash.

I have tried reinstalling whatsapp and setting the chown like in [Restore Whatsapp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169607/restore-whatsapp?rq=1) but that doesn't work. I even tried setting SELinux to permissive and have no luck.

Here's the logcat just in case: https://pastebin.pl/view/b8fe76fb

Owh ya, I forgot to mention that my msgstore.db is sized 3.58gb :)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to restore your messages? I have the same problem. Trying to restore old msgstore.db.crypt14 databases is stuck at 44% for a long time but eventually fails. In the log it's saying that the database disk image is malformed

Comment: @TheLostOne Short answer: No. I tried everything I could, and it seems that there's a problem with the database and how new version whatsapp handle the error. I just gave up and start fresh since there's nothing I can do. I did store the old msgstore.db and old version of whatsapp so I can view it offline if I ever need it. Still hoping that someone could find the solution, but until then, I don't think there's an easy solution